# Adwords API - too slow on hosting

Tags: asp.net, api, hosting, google-ads-api

our hosting server is seeing a huge delay when calling Adwords API. I use ASP.NET and API functions delay approx. 3 seconds. On my local PC everything is fast (approx. 400 ms).

Can you help me?

Thanks